# Bibliography title

Tags: bibliographies, babel, naming

I can't change the "Bibliography" to "Βιβλιογραφία"

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\addto\captionsngreek{\renewcommand{\refname}{Βιβλιογραφία}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/home/Petros/images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newlength{\drop}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib} 

\begin{document}
.....
.....
.....
\printindex
\selectlanguage{english}
\print bibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It should be `\captionsgreek`, but you have `\captionsngreek`; moreover you should modify `\bibname`, not `\refname`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three distinct issues:

1. `\captionsngreek` is wrong and should be `\captionsgreek`
2. The `report` class uses `\bibname`, not `\refname`
3. You're setting the bibliography with English as the main language, so you should do

   ```
   \addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Βιβλιογραφία}}
   ```

   or, more simply,

   ```
   \printbibliography[title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]
   ```

Comment: I tried them both but the \addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Βιβλιογραφία}} remove the bibliography title with no title. The \printbibliography[heading=Βιβλιογραφία] gave me the error "Missing \endcsname inserted" and "Package biblatex Error:" for the Βιβλιογραφία .. I am tryng for 3 days now, with no other issue or error and its rather long latex (3500 lines)

Comment: @PetrosMourouzis I fixed the suggestion, sorry for the mistake.